# SQL join count and select query

Tags: sql

I have two tables, one is a list of 'gangs' and one is a list of 'gang_members' the gang_members.gang_id refers to the gang.id they are in, I know how to count all the members in one gang, but I need to join the following queries into one:

```
SELECT * FROM gangs LIMIT 8
SELECT count(gang_id) FROM gangs_members WHERE gang_id = <GANG ID>
```

[image]

I think this is possible, I could do it in a loop while it's going through the gangs but that would be inefficient

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to get.  Please provide some sample result data.

Comment: Thought it was pretty clear, my bad. I need it to count the amount of members that are all the gangs I get from the first query

Comment: JOINing and AGGREGATING are very basic SQL concepts.   You should do some tutorials on these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT A.*, B.RC
FROM gangs A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT gang_id, COUNT(*) AS RC FROM gangs_members GROUP BY gang_id) B ON A.gang_id=B.gang_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like this

```
SELECT count(gang_id) 
FROM gangs_members 
WHERE gang_id IN (SELECT gang_id FROM gangs LIMIT 8)
```